# How can I call .net application/exe in pre-commit hook

Tags: git, visual-studio, githooks

I wanted to validate xml file before the file being committed to the repository. For this I have created .net application which accepts the file and validates the xml file and if file is valid it will return true else it will return false.

My question here is, how can I call .net application in pre-commit hook.

Below is the pre-commit code snippet

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM); do
  # Check if the file is an XML file
  if [[ $file == *.xml ]]; then
    # Perform XML validation using the xmlvalidator.exe program
    path_to_validator="./Utilities/xmlvalidator.exe"
    validation_result=$(mono "$path_to_validator" "$file" 2>&1)

    # Check the output of the validator program
    if [[ $validation_result != *"Valid XML"* ]]; then
      echo "Error: Invalid XML file: $file"
      echo "Validation Result: $validation_result"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
done

exit 0
```

When I execute this, its error out in the line

path_to_validator="./Utilities/xmlvalidator.exe
And error is- path_to_validator: command not found.

Can anybody help me out.

I am using visual studio 2019 and windows OS for git repository.